# Singleton or Static Logger?

Tags: c#

My current C# application is a single executable (EXE) and a few DLLs (so multiple binaries) and I want to create a LOGGER (some simple custom logger that writes to a single text file no matter where it is being called from - and this should be available in all the binaries (exe and dll's) - note that it is a single threaded application.

Right now I have a DLL (Logger) and it has a class (Log) with a method (trace) which logs, each project adds a reference to this DLL (Logger) and creates its own instance (pass in a file name) and then calls the .Trace(...) function - works fine ...

But I would rather not have to create many different trace files (minimum one per project) and having to create a new instance of Logger each time seems repetitive ... So I was looking into either creating a STATIC logger class or using a SINGLTON ... I am just not sure which is best and why ...

I was hoping someone could maybe point me in the right direction on this, what is the best way to create a logger class (it will be its own DLL) that will be used by many projects (referenced) and they should all write to the same log file...?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Check out log4net http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: any reason you don't want to use log4net?

Comment: What logging framework do you use, if you use one?

Comment: +1 for log4net.  This is a solved problem, no reason to reinvent the wheel here unless you are just trying to learn something.

Comment: There is a single EXE running... and I just want to use some simple logger, all the big ones have all these config files and it just gets to be more of a headache then it is worth for this simple little program I am ... updating ... it really should've all been in a single project ... the joys of maintenance on legacy

Comment: While I have never used log4net I would also second using a already made solution.  Why re-invent the wheel?  I have used the enterprise library often and found it's logging capabilities more than adequate.  Unless you are barred from using third party dlls this is the route i would go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You choose between `Singleton` and `Static` logger the same way you always choose between the two: Do you want to be able to *override* methods (or use a `Logging` interface)? If you use a singleton, you have the opportunity to override methods to change functionality. You can even abstract the behavior away behind an interface.

With a static class you are now and forever tied to that class, and any changes affect everyone.

When dealing with my own systems, i have moved towards singleton instanced objects. It gives a level of flexibility not available with static classes.

Comment: "If you use a singleton, you have the the opportunity to override methods..."?  Don't just ignore the fact that singletons and inheritance do not play well together at all.